# I have an array of regex I am replacing with the same character. How would I use or "|" with my regex to lower array count?

Tags: php, regex

I have more setup in my arrays but to keep it simple I'm only placing the ones with which I want to group together using or "|".

```
$patterns = array();
$patterns[1] = "/(?:\:)/";
$patterns[2] = "/(?:\-_)/";
$patterns[3] = "/(?:\_-)/";
$replacements = array();
$replacements[1] = "-";
$replacements[2] = "-";
$replacements[3] = "-";
preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $data['string']);
```

I have tried different attempts with no success. Below is an attempt of grouping the desired array:

```
$patterns = array();
$patterns[1] = "/(?::|-_|_-|)/";
$replacements = array();
$replacements[1] = "-"
```

All my other arrays have a unique **$replacments**. Leaving the original setup works as I want but I simply want to lower the arrays count by grouping these 3 into 1. This regex actually works as intended but for my scenario I had to leave my original setup as was/is.It was giving mixed results because of the order of the replacements. Triggering the replacement in one group gave weird results.

Comment: `preg_replace('/(?::|-_|_-|)/', '-', $data['string']);` should work.

Comment: @anubhava - This is not working. I tried that setting it as one of my **$patterns** with the desired **$replacements** "-". As I stated I have more arrays using **$patterns** and **$replacements** which I didn't put up here. I only wanted to group the following into one **$patterns** array with the same intended **$replacements** array and it didn't work.

Comment: You need to provide some example input and expected output also. Whatever you have presented in question this regex is suffice for that.

Comment: This regex is working but the order of the replacements for my case required that I only group the later 2 **"-_|_-"**and the first 1 **":"** to be left as a single $patterns array. My initail results when checking out the regex you provided was an error on my end. @anubhava - You should put this as the answer so that I can accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since replacement is same `-` you can combine all your matching regex with `|` and use a simpler version of `preg_replace`:

```
$data['string'] = preg_replace('/(?::|-_|_-|)/', '-', $data['string']);
```

Here `(?::|-_|_-|)` will match a `:` or `-_` or `_-`.